# DisplayDateFormat is not working as expected for Telerik RadDatePicker ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik

I am working on two already existing ASP.NET Web projects. I got an issue that DateOfBirth is showing in MM/dd/yyyy format instead of dd/MM/yyyy in telerik:RadDatePicker. So i have added following code in both projects.

```html
<div>
  <telerik:RadDatePicker RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="StartDate" ClientEvents-OnDateSelected="OnDateSelected" runat="server" Culture="en-US" meta:resourcekey="StartDateResource1">
    <Calendar ShowRowHeaders="False" RenderMode="Lightweight" UseColumnHeadersAsSelectors="False" UseRowHeadersAsSelectors="False"></Calendar>
    <DateInput DateFormat="d/M/yyyy" DisplayDateFormat="d/M/yyyy"
    </DateInput>
  </telerik:RadDatePicker>
</div>
```

DisplayDateFormat is working fine in Project-1, but it fails in Project-2. I tried different formats. Also i copied the entire page from Project-1 to Project-2, then also issue persists. I tried the same code in different pages and it always fails in Project-2.

I have verified the .Net framework and Telerik version in both projects and it seems to be the same.
Does anyone have idea on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer myself. There was following code snippet in BasePage.cs file

```
datePicker.DateInput.DisplayDateFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;  
            datePicker.Culture = new CultureInfo(ResourceContext.Culture);
```

I have removed the above part from code and it is working fine.